# DynamoDB Application Architecture

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

We are using DynamoDB with node.js and Express to create REST APIs. We have started to go with Dynamo on the backend, for simplicity of operations.

We have started to use  the DynamoDB Document SDK from AWS Labs to simplify usage, and make it easy to work with JSON documents. To instantiate a client to use, we need to do the following:

```
AWS = require('aws-sdk');
Doc = require("dynamodb-doc");
var Dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var DocClient = new Doc.DynamoDB(Dynamodb);
```

My question is, where do those last two steps need to take place, in order to ensure data integrity? I’m concerned about an object that is waiting for something happen in Dynamo, being taken over by another process, and getting the data swapped, resulting in incorrect data being sent back to a client, or incorrect data being written to the database.

We have three parts to our REST API. We have the main server.js file, that starts express and the HTTP server, and assigns resources to it, sets up logging, etc. We do the first two steps of creating the connection to Dynamo, creating the AWS and Doc requires, at that point. Those vars are global in the app. We then, depending on the route being followed through the API, call a controller that parses up the input from the rest call. It then calls a model file, that does the interacting with Dynamo, and provides the response back to the controller, which formats the return package along with any errors, and sends it to the client. The model is simply a group of methods that essentially cover the same area of the app. We would have a user model, for instance, that covers things like login and account creation in an app.

I have done the last two steps above for creating the dynamo object in two places. One, I have simply placed them in one spot, at the top of each model file. I do not reinstantiate them in the methods below, I simply use them. I have also instantiated them within the methods, when we are preparing to the make the call to Dynamo, making them entirely local to the method, and pass them to a secondary function if needed. This second method has always struck me as the safest way to do it. However, under load testing, I have run into situations where we seem to have overwhelmed the outgoing network connections, and I start getting errors telling me that the DynamoDB end point is unavailable in the region I’m running in. I believe this is from the additional calls required to make the connections.

So, the question is, is creating those objects local to the model file, safe, or do they need to be created locally in the method that uses them? Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be safe creating just one instance of those clients and sharing them in your code, but that isn't related to your underlying concern.

Concurrent access to various records in DynamoDB is still something you have to deal with.  It is possible to have different requests attempt writes to the object at the same time.  This is possible if you have concurrent requests on a single server, but is especially true when you have multiple servers.

Writes to DynamoDB are atomic only at the individual item.  This means if your logic requires multiple updates to separate items potentially in separate tables there is no way to guarantee all or none of those changes are made.  It is possible only some of them could be made.

DynamoDB natively supports [conditional writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) so it is possible to ensure specific conditions are met, such as specific attributes still have certain values, otherwise the write will fail.

With respect to making too many requests to DynamoDB... unless you are overwhelming your machine there shouldn't be any way to overwhelm the DynamoDB API.  If you are performing more read/writes that you have provisioned you will receive errors indicating provisioned throughput has been exceeded, but the API itself is still functioning as intended under these conditions.

Comment: FYI DynamoDB has a transaction library in the Java SDK (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-transaction-library/) that can operate over multiple tables but does not appear to have this in the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Interesting. That makes it simpler, I suppose. I am aware of the other issues with dynamo, that's just simple database issues in a stateless world, where you're not locking records. Node.js is a rather unique environment, in it's threading model.  And the too many requests to dynamo I think was related more to DNS/network issues than dynamo. It was a bit weird, to say the least.